# limited area of a curve

Tags: calculus, curves

The answer is 8au but I have a difficult time to understand why, can anybody explain? Question: Calculate the total area that is limited by the curve $$y = x^3 -4x$$ and the $x$-axis. Also if the question doesn't make sense, it's because I directly translated it so ask if there is something which doesn't make sense!

Comment: Everything that is in the example page which shows how to solve some of the upcomming questions but I get another answer on this one than it is in the solution.

Comment: What answer do you get? $0$? Something else? And how do you get that answer?

Comment: What is "8au" ?

Comment: yes I got 0 and not 8au, au = area units

Comment: You got $0$ because the area from $x = 0$ to $x = 2$ has been counted with the wrong sign. Areas are never negative, but integrals can be. You need to calculate the two areas separately, then add them together.

Comment: Still can't figure it out :/ Can you be so nice and post full solution? ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture ! Then you should see that the area is given by

$\int_{-2}^0 (x^3-4x)dx +|\int_{0}^2 (x^3-4x)dx|$.